# Distance from str to the end (python)

Tags: python

Ok, so I'm trying to get the distance in a str (called bigstr), from a small other variable called smallstr until it ends.
For example:

```
bigstr = 'What are you saying?'
smallstr = 'you'

then
distance = 8
```

I'm trying to use re, but I'm a total noob with this library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if you need re for that, following should suffice:

**Using split:**

```
>>> bigstr = 'What are you saying?'
>>> smallstr = 'you'
>>> bigstr.split(smallstr)
['What are ', ' saying?']
>>> words = bigstr.split(smallstr)
>>> len(words[0])
9
>>> len(words[1])
8
```

**Using index:**

```
>>> bigstr.index(smallstr)
9
>>> len(bigstr) - bigstr.index(smallstr) -len(smallstr)
8
```

Also you will notice that `distance` is 9 and not 8 because it counts spaces - `'What are '`

You can alsways use strip to remove any spaces, if that concerns you.

**If you still want to use re:** Then use search

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(smallstr)
>>> match = pattern.search(bigstr)       
>>> match.span()
(9, 12)
>>>
```

Comment: +1, but he seems to want the distance from the end of the needle to the end of the haystack, not from the beginning of the haystack to the beginning of the needle. Fortunately, that is easy: `len(bigstr) - len(smallstr) - bigstr.index(smallstr)`.

Comment: Both these answers count the distance from the start of the string, not until the end of the string.  That's why you get 9 and not 8.

Comment: @jchl @Karl Knechtel: Thanks a lot, I misunderstood the distance part. I have added the modifications.

Comment: I've picked this one cause its the most complete one, but @jchi reply was useful as well. Thanks :D

Answer (score 5):

```
distance = len(bigstr) - (bigstr.index(smallstr) + len(smallstr))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bigstr = 'What are you saying?'
smallstr = 'you'

import re
match = re.search(smallstr, bigstr)
distance = len(bigstr) - match.end()
```